# String content and user_input doesnt let me input more than one word

Tags: java, string, input, output

I'm building an application in java that should let the user input some data, but it only reads the 1st word

```
System.out.print("Write to file: ");
writedText = user_input.next();

String content = writedText;

File file = new File(Putanja2);  

FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
bw.write(content);
bw.close();

System.out.println("File is made");
```

Answer (score 3):

`.next()` will only read to the first whitespace of your input.  You will want to use `.nextLine()` to get multiple inputs which are separated by whitespace.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question, then this

```
writedText = user_input.next();
```

Should be

```
writedText = user_input.nextLine();
```

Per the [`nextLine()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine%28%29) javadoc,

> Advances this scanner past the current line and returns the input that was skipped. This method returns the rest of the current line, excluding any line separator at the end. The position is set to the beginning of the next line.

Comment: But now it skips the code and only do the System.out.print
It shows only the : Write to file: File is made

Comment: Add two `nextLine()` your previous input must be like `nextInt()` which leaves a newline in the buffer, so you're getting one empty line.